# iOS RTP library/tutorial/example

Tags: iphone, ios, messaging, rtp

I'm wondering about the availability of a library to send and receive realtime text updates (between device and server) in a messaging-type app. I'm not really sure where to look, or what to search for, but my preliminary searches haven't had much success. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about XMPP (Extensible Messaging and Presence Protocol)? It has a very decent framework in Objective-C - http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/.

If it's an option for you, WebSockets also come handy here. Try using [zimt](http://github.com/esad/zimt) for instance or [UnittWebSocketClient API](http://code.google.com/p/unitt/wiki/UnittWebSocketClient).